# Getting an image from a GMap.NET.GMapControl without it being visible

Tags: c#, google-maps, openstreetmap, gmap.net

I would like to get a map from an online source (whether than be Google Maps, OpenStreetMap, or other) and be able to (1) display it on a form, and (2) save it as an image. These two functions are separate.

After a bit of research I concluded that the `GMap.NET.GMapControl` was probably the best way of doing this and I implemented this method. However, I have hit a snag when trying to save the image.

I am saving the image by generating a jpeg from the control using its `ToImage()` method. This works, but only when the map is visible on screen. In my application I need to be able to generate the image without rendering it to screen.

If the `GMapControl` is not visible, the jpeg is just a black rectangle. The test code below demonstrates this. The form contains two `GMapControl` controls. If both are visible I get two identical jpeg images. If one is hidden, the corresponding jpeg is blank.

Is there a way I can get the map image using a `GMapControl` without plotting it to screen? Or should I take a different approach and use something else? The more lightweight the better as far as I am concerned.

(My first attempt was using the `WebBrowser` control. I moved on from this because I was getting all the borders etc. as well as the map. I tried to exclude everything but the div containing the map, but then I lost everything ; I suspect this may have been because the map div was nested and I was hiding its parent...)

```
public partial class testForm : Form
{
    public testForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void testForm_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        gMapControl2.Hide(); // this results in a blank jpg image for gMapControl2

        // Plot the same map to both gMapControls...
        PlotMap(gMapControl1);
        PlotMap(gMapControl2);

        // Excuse the clunky wait method here ; it was due to a 'cross-thread' error when using the event raised by the gMapControl
        // It serves the purpose here.
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); }).Wait(); // wait for 5 seconds to give maps plenty of time to render

        WriteBitmap(gMapControl1, $@"E:\Test_gMapControl1.jpg");
        WriteBitmap(gMapControl2, $@"E:\Test_gMapControl2.jpg");
    }
    private void PlotMap(GMapControl gMapControl)
    {

        gMapControl.MapProvider = GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
        GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
        gMapControl.ShowCenter = false;
        gMapControl.MinZoom = 1;
        gMapControl.MaxZoom = 25;
        gMapControl.Zoom = 10;
        gMapControl.Position = new PointLatLng(10, 10); // centered on 10 lat, 10 long

    }
    private void WriteBitmap(GMapControl gMapControl, string filename)
    {
        Image b = gMapControl.ToImage();
        b.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Saving the map as an image, at least for Google Maps, is against their terms of service.

Comment: I thought it was permitted as per Google's [Permissions Guidelines](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/#:~:text=Fair%20use,license%20from%20the%20copyright%20holder). _"As long as you follow the guidance on this page, and attribute the content correctly, feel free to move forward with your project."_ Anyway - I am happy to use Open License mapping e.g. OSM. My question is a technical one, not a legal one.

Comment: I know your question is not about legal aspects. I just mentioned that it felt like it's against their TOS. Maybe check their [TOS](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#3.-license.) in particular point 3.2.3. Google has an API for static maps (maps as images) which is billed just like all their other mapping products. If you need to pay to have a static map image, then it makes sense that you are not allowed to just make a screenshot and use it.

Comment: Understood, thanks. FWIW, my understanding is that it is permitted. [Google Permissions GeoGuidelines](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/) _"Generally speaking, as long as you're following our Terms of Service, these guidelines, and you're attributing properly, you can use our maps and imagery. In fact, we love seeing creative applications of Google Maps, Google Earth, and Street View."_

Comment: The most important part being *"as long as you're following our Terms of Service"* - and probably your use case (how you are using it and for what purpose) but we don't know about that. The documentation you linked to clearly states it is for *creative applications / non-commercial use*. Only **you** can find out whether your use case will be against their TOS, or not.

Comment: Noted. My question is a technical one, not a legal one.